Mount needs manual action after each reboot for it to work
I mounted a local ssd drive (ext4) called "data" using nemo on Linux Mint 22. It works fine. It is displayed, can be read and written.
When I use any file within that mount for another application e.g. the keepassxc I cannot access any of those files UNLESS I manually select "data" in Nemo. After that everything works fine. I would prefer to get rid of that extra click.
Any Mount-Options I am missing?
Mount-Config is:
mount  | grep data
/dev/nvme1n1p3 on /media/guacamole/data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

I have full permissions (rwx) to that folder, the mount is displayed under "devices" in nemo


Where did you define the mount, and with what options?

Did you add the record in /etc/fstab?

@RomeoNinov Your question kindof was the answer. I expected that nemo does that for me. Added it manually. Problem solved

Added as answer :)

To make filesystem mounted on every reboot you need to add specific record in /etc/fstab. Also there you can define some parameters if you need (for example mount filesystem as readonly). So the solution is to add record and exec mountall to mount the filesystems which are not mounted at the moment.
Do not forget you need to exec these operations (edit the file and exec mountall) as root user
